# Twitter Bootstrap/Unify center variable amount of images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, center

I want to create a call-to-action box with centered content

The box is contains two rows
the first row has the title and the second a variable amount of images, with a maximum of 12 (if greater than, then it will be three or more rows).

The text get perfectly centered using `.text-center`.
However i cannot create a div with the width of the content.

What i have now:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style=" padding: 10px 0 0;">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 animated fadeInLeft">
                    <span class="color-green">Title</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-9 center-block">
                    <!-- Content / Images-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried multiple setups but the center-block doesn't seem to place the `col-md-9` in the middle. (even though it does apply `margin: 0 auto;`)

What can i do to create equal width images in the center of their container, with variable amount. I'm using Unify Template which is based on Twitter Bootstrap 3

Comment: Have you tried using col-offset?

Comment: Col-offset would be possible if the amount is static and even. However the content is variable and in default case odd amount (the content is not likely to change but it must be supported). We have currently 9 elements so it's unreachable with using offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `text-center` affects on `inline`-level elements(children) only, you need to make them inline. It's clear. So all you need is to make `<div class="col-md-9 center-block">` inline. Do it:

```css
.center-block {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

If you want to push not more than 12 images in one line without javascript, I think there's the only way:

```
.center-block img {
  width: 8.2%;
}
```